# Does a materialize view refresh in its creation?

Tags: oracle, materialized-view

I create a materialized view with the following cast function. It does not give me an error during creation although it exists an error. But refresh gives the error.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW XXXX_ROW_MV
BUILD DEFERRED
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT
    CAST ('null' AS NUMBER)   currency_rate,
     CAST ('null' AS NUMBER)   conversion_factor;
```

Does this mean that materialized views compile until it is being refreshed?

refresh can be done by using following code

```
begin
  DBMS_MVIEW.refresh('XXXX_ROW_MV');

end;
```

Comment: Try selecting from the MV you just "created". if it has data, it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BUILD DEFERRED` clause in the `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` DDL statement causes the actual population to be deferred until the first refresh.

While Oracle parses the actual SQL used to populate the view, it does not execute it & will therefore not pick up "runtime" problems.

This is easily demonstrated.

Parsing error, due to `NONSENSE` not being a datatype:

```
SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW PARSINGERROR
BUILD DEFERRED
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT
    CAST ('null' AS NONSENSE) as parsing_error
     from dual; 


    CAST ('null' AS NONSENSE) as parsing_error
                    *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype

SQL>
```

Runtime error, that won't get picked up as it doesn't analyse the actual values involved, and is unaware that the included string isn't a number:

```
SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW RUNTIMEERROR
BUILD DEFERRED
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT
    CAST ('notanumber' AS number) as runtime_error
     from dual;  

Materialized view created.

SQL>

SQL> begin
  2  DBMS_MVIEW.refresh('RUNTIMEERROR');
  3  end;
  4  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2566
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2779
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2748
ORA-06512: at line 2


SQL>
```